# Retrieve Output from Method

Tags: c#

How can I get the output from the following method?

```
public static string getLimitedWords(string str,int NumberOfWords)
{
  string[] Words= str.Split(' ');
  string _return=string.Empty;                 

  if(Words.Length<=NumberOfWords)
  {
        _return = str;
  }
  else
  {
        for(int i=0;i<NumberOfWords;i++)
        {
              _return+=Words.GetValue(i).ToString()+" ";
        } 
  } 
  return _return.ToString();
}
```

Comment: What does "display the method" mean?

Comment: Display where? Do you have another question?

Comment: Jordie91 doesn't seem to be a native English speaker ; it's highly probable that "display" is the literal translation of a dutch word...

Answer (score 1):

If debugging, try `System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(getLimitedWords(yourString,yourNumberOfWords));`

If using ASP.NET, try `Page.Response.Write(getLimitedWords(yourString,yourNumberOfWords));`

If using Console, try `System.Console.Write(getLimitedWords(yourString,yourNumberOfWords));`

Comment: Or, if in the debugger, just hover the mouse over the returned value.

Answer (score 0):

Such a poorly asked question, but I can't resist optimizing your method:

```
public static string getLimitedWords(string str,int NumberOfWords)
{
    return String.Join(" ",str.Split(' ').Take(NumberOfWords).ToArray());
}
```

As for the answer to your question, I can't figure out what you're asking. Rephrase the question and you might get a more useful answer.

Comment: Where did that Take function come from?

Comment: Great, now he probably has to upgrade to the latest .Net framework to use your optimized method :)

Answer (score 0):

The output of the method is a `string`. Which means that depending upon your platform, you can display it any number of ways.  The following snippet from a C# Console application is one such way:

```
string str =  "This is a String of Words";
int numberOfWords = 5;
Console.WriteLine(getLimitedWords(str, numberOfWords));
Console.Read();
```

The output is:
      `This is a string of`

You can also assign the output to a string and display that any number of ways:

```
string output = getLimitedWords(str, numberOfWords);
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm just trying to guess what you need here:

```
String answer = getLimitedWords( str, NumberOfWords);

Console.WriteLine ( answer );
```

Could it be something like this?